# Is the HDMI output on the Xoom limited to cloning the display or can it be a secondary screen?

Tags: screen, video-out, motorola-xoom

Is the HDMI output on the Xoom (or indeed any of the newer tablet devices) capable of displaying different imagery to that being shown on the device's screen?  Is it limited to cloning?  Can the internal screen be blanked (e.g. if watching a movie on a bigger screen).

I've seen examples of iPad games that display a secondary screen on the device itself when outputting to a TV (e.g. racing games showing the map on the device which is doubling up as the wheel).

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, it looks like Motorola is not offering that at launch but will try to support it in future upgrades: [Official Motorola FAQ](https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/61611/~/motorola-xoom---hdmi)

Unless I am reading that wrong.

Comment: Thanks for that link.  "Mirror Mode" is available and has been shown on lots of videos but "HDCP via HDMI" seems to be something coming later.